# Google Sheets Circular Dropdown Dependency

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-data-validation

Suppose we have 2 columns `Id` & `Name` which contained in `sheet1`. Now in `sheet2` have dropdown for `Id` & `Name` which user can select and it `Lookup` value for each other (select `Id` from dropdown, `Name` automatically filled, and vice-versa).

Is this possible? Because it sounds like circular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a circular dependency. You can either have **ID** dropdown or **Name** dropdown and counterpart of it will need to be secured by **`VLOOKUP`** formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A2:B, 2, 0), )
```

[image: 0]

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, {Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!A2:A}, 2, 0), )
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AiFAYeBEMgx79OUsTXZt6cX7R4YEc9pZLipdHkQbPRA/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: huh, i suppose this scenario is common since searching by ``Id`` is a hassle, and searching through ``Name`` is more convenient, but ``Name`` may contain duplicate so ``Id`` also necessary. If circular lookup isn't possible, is it possible to display more than 1 column in dropdown list?

Comment: what do you mean by: more than one?

Comment: i.e. ``Id`` dropdown contains list of ``Id`` (by range selection). Is it possible to include 2nd column ``Name`` in that dropdown list? this way only 1 dropdown needed

Comment: no, that's not possible. it would be if you would merge those two columns under one and then output it under a dropdown

Comment: alright, conclusion is "No". Thanks for the insight